# Files are included in foreign target using CMake and Visual Studio

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019

I am working on medium-sized project, which uses CMake.
Lately I recognized weird behavior, when generating project files for Visual Studio 2019.
The problem:

Let `A` and `B` be targets. `A` is an executable, which depends on `B`, a static library. The relationship is established using `target_link_libraries`.

If I load this project into Visual Studio I am presented with the following directory structure:

```
Solution/
- Project A/
  - src/
    - sources_of_a.cpp
    - ...
  - B/ # <- WHY?
    - all_sources_of_b.cpp
      ...
- Project B/
  - src/
    - sources_of_b.cpp
      ...
```

Honestly, I don't even know how to better describe this problem, let alone what may cause it.
All I know is that the sources of B should not be part of A's source set.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Notable side notes:

- B is actually a target imported via `FetchContent` & `add_subdirectory`
- I am actually using CPM over FetchContent; however, I tried FetchContent only, problem persists
- This doesn't happen to all of my targets

Comment: Can you please provide your CMake code showing how you setup the `A` and `B` targets?

Comment: @squareskittles I managed to fix it. However, I still appreciate you trying to help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were the calls to `target_source`, where headers where specified as public sources. I.e. like this:

```
target_sources(
    B
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/source_of_b_.cpp
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/B/header_of_b.hpp
)
```

Removing the `PUBLIC` marker fixes the issue. Change it to this:

```
target_sources(
    B
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/source_of_b_.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/B/header_of_b.hpp
)
```

Apparently I completely misunderstood the semantics, *although the CMake documentation is best in class*.